# How to get JSON object from link with Javascript Traverson HAL

Tags: javascript, json, rest, spring-data, hateoas

I have the following JSON object:

```
{

  "_embedded" : {

    "carPriceStreams" : [ {

      "carClassCurrency" : {

        "carClass" : {

          "carClass" : {

            "code" : "A542",

          },

          "_links" : {

            "car" : {

              "href" : "http://localhost:9001/api/car/2"

            }

          }

        },

        "creationDate" : "2015-07-01"

      },

      "_links" : {

        "self" : {

          "href" : "http://localhost:9001/api/carPriceStreams/1"

        },

        "carPriceStream" : {

          "href" : "http://localhost:9001/api/carPriceStreams/1"

        },

        "carPrices" : {

          "href" : "http://localhost:9001/api/carPriceStreams/1/carPrices"

        }

      }

    },...
```

I make use of the [Traverson JavaScript library](https://github.com/traverson/traverson) and [the HAL adapter for Traverson](https://github.com/traverson/traverson-hal) to get the object:

```
traverson.registerMediaType(TraversonJsonHalAdapter.mediaType, 
                     TraversonJsonHalAdapter);
var api = traverson
            .from(url + "/api")
            .jsonHal();
api
  .newRequest()
  .follow('carPriceStreams')
  .getResource(//...
```

For each carPriceStream, I want to follow links to its car and retrieve that car resource. How can I do this?

I've already tried

```
api
  .newRequest()
  .follow('carPriceStreams', 'car')
  .getResource(//...
```

But I get a `HalLinkError`.

Comment: Does traverson consider embedded items to be links that you can follow?

Comment: My understanding based on [this](https://github.com/traverson/traverson-hal#embedded-documents) is yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a traverson user but your `car` object is not a direct child of `carPriceStreams`.

Can you try this ?

```
  .follow('carPriceStreams', 'carClassCurrency', 'carClass', 'car')
```